# In Perl, how can I check the step between array elements?

Tags: perl

Say I have an array that looks like this:

```
@var = ( 1, 59, 120, 181 );
```

How can I get an array of steps between each element, such that:

```
@var_steps = ( 58, 61, 61 );
```

I know that I could use an iterator to do this using `i` and `i + 1` for each index, but is there a nicer way?

Answer (score 4):

```
my @var = ( 1, 59, 120, 181 );
my @var_steps = map { $var[$_+1] - $var[$_] } 0 .. $#var-1;
```

or

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(pairwise);
my @a1 = @var[0..$#var-1];
my @a2 = @var[1..$#var];
my @var_steps = pairwise { $b - $a } @a1, @a2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution with `map` fine, but here’s another look at it. With a helper function:

```
sub zip_with(&\@\@) {
    my ($f, $xs, $ys) = @_;
    my @zs;

    my $min = @$xs < @$ys ? @$xs : @$ys;
    for my $i (0 .. $min - 1) {
        push @zs, &$f($$xs[$i], $$ys[$i]);
    }
    return @zs;
}
```

You can get the adjacent differences like this:

```
my @var_steps = zip_with { $_[1] - $_[0] } @vars, @vars[1..$#vars];
```

Comment: `Type of arg 3 to main::zip_with must be array (not array slice)`

Comment: @mpapec: Ah, that’s what I get for not testing this. You would need to do `@{[@vars[1..$#vars]]}` or assign to a temporary in order to make a new array from the slice, at which point it seems not worth doing.

Comment: yes, something like that. Just a side note, `&$f($$xs[$i], $$ys[$i])` is more commonly written as ___ `$f->($xs->[$i], $ys->[$i])`

Comment: @mpapec: True. These days I use Perl mostly for code golf, so I don’t mind the shorter form, but the arrow is probably clearer.